# ASP.NET 4.0 , SQL 2008 Web development and deployment Cloud or Shared Hosting?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, cloud-hosting

Just to give you a fair idea, I am new to the web development / hosting world and planning to develop a Multilingual Social networking Web Applications in ASP.NET 4.0 , expected the content to deliver in many countries German, France, China, India and MiddleEast. My question is will Cloud Hosting provides a development environment? or should i buy software and develop in my system?. Which is the best hosting model for my scenario. I do know there will not be many users and expecting a steady growth.

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Buy software, develop on own server. Clous HOSTING is clout HOSTING. You want test and development environment locally. Buying in this case, though, means... well ;) - 0 USD (express edition of visual studio).
- Best hosting model? Hm. TOtally depends. On volume, for example.  would go with some cheap shared hosting unless other needs arise.
- Start shared hosting wise. ASP.NET 4.0 shared hosting should become available soonish (This month) as ASP.NET is realeased on the 12th of April.